# How to calculate summary and boxplot in minitab data with conditional case?

Tags: minitab, minitab-16

I am trying to create summary statistics and boxplots between Pulse1 and Smokes with the condition as follows

1. Pulse1 & Smokes==No
2. Pulse1 & Smokes==Yes

Smokes "No" = The person is not a smoker

Smokes "Yes" = The person is a smoker

I have tried to modify by simply separate "No" and "Yes" in the SMOKES header, but it took me a lot of time since the data is big, and the screenshot below took only a few examples. How can i do this without modifying the data as i done before? I'm open for any suggestions, thank you so much

[image: Minitab Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. This looks like really elementary Minitab so perhaps I am misunderstanding your question.

I've loaded Minitab's example data set Pulse.MTW, which looks like your example data with some variables coded as numbers rather than text: 
[image]

- menu Stat > Basic Statistics > Display Basic Statistics...
- Set:
  Variables: Pulse1,   By Variables: Smokes
- Click Graphs... and tick
  Boxplot of data
- Click OK a couple of times

[image]
[image]

Is that what you wanted?